# access to methods when you import module

Tags: python, class, methods, import

Good afternoon, guys. Listen I have a question in regards of methods and imports.
Let's say I have following code:

```
import random

l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

random.shuffle(l)
print(l)


shuf_obj = random.SystemRandom()
shuf_obj.shuffle(l)
print(l)
```

In both cases I will be able to shuffle my list l.
What I don't understand is how come just by importing module random I have access to instance method through dot notation? Basically why we can directly access shuffle method instead of first instantiating the class and then access the method.

Answer (score 0):

The functions supplied by this module are actually bound methods of a hidden instance of the :class:`random.Random` class. - [SourceCode](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.11/Doc/library/random.rst)

Comment: This is true, but your link is to docs in the source code. Here is the actual [module source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/8cf8a6820e3fa885ac6159b8002f5e8d7834ca83/Lib/random.py#L824)

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga can you explain me mechanics of how it's working? Correct me if I am wrong. So when we import this module three is already an instance that been instantiated inside that module? Thank you

Comment: @andrewmamchyn yes, exactly. Did you look at the code in the link, it shows exactly where that happens

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).